# Error while using android-ndk-r8d with OpenCV

Tags: android, opencv, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I'm recently start studying OpenCV library for which I use NVIDIA's Tegra Android Developer Pack 2.0r4(TADP) which includes all setup you can see [this](https://developer.nvidia.com/tegra-android-development-pack) link. The Error is occur when I try to use jni, I import OpenCV library with some tutorial and one HelloJNI project, OpenCV library is import successfully but the openCV sample Project which has jni folder gives Error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
**make: ** No rule to make target `../../sdk/native/jni/OpenCV.mk'.**  Stop.    OpenCV Sample - native-activity         C/C++ Problem
```

and the HelloJni project also have jni folder which gives Error

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [clean-hello-jni-armeabi] Error 1 HelloJni            C/C++ Problem
```